# Can I ask which bicycle I can buy?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic, asking-questions, moderators

I am very new to cycling and I don't know which cycle best suits me. I live in India. 
My doubt is whether, I can ask which MTB cycle I can buy? I will state my budget.

Please let me know soon, I am in need of an MTB cycle.

Comment: Is there someone who could let me know whether I can ask this question in bicycles.stackexchange.com? Or at least let me know if this question is valid or not.

Comment: I didn't get any positive or negative reply from anyone, so I am adding the moderator tag to this question.

Comment: At least rate the question either of the ways. So that I know I will get an answer one day or the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally open-ended "shopping" questions are frowned upon. See [Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)!

There are probably 100 "What kind of bike should I buy?" questions posted already, so you should probably start by searching for those.

You will likely notice that the better questions have specific criteria - like this one about a [bike for recreation and fitness that will fit in a car](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/looking-to-buy-a-bicycle-for-exercising-and-recreational-activities-that-will-f).

The better questions say things like "I have characteristic A, B, C and needs 1, 2, 3.  What should I look for in a bike that will meet those characteristics and needs?"

Examples are things like What to look for in a bike for a 6'6" person, or a person over 350 lbs, or a bike that will be used for long distance touring, or to tow children.

Thanks for asking here first, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 4):

You should also put yourself in the position of a potential responder. If they were to say "brand x was a really good buy from my perspective", they are likely to just invite responses (if you're lucky), and anonymous downvotes (if you're not) from people who think brand x is the biggest pile of.....

So pretty soon everything just becomes a subjective argument. What's the point of that? That wouldn't help you work out what bike to buy.